# How to query AddressBook contacts according to the given number？

Tags: ios, addressbook

I use  the method loop all the contacts in addressbook， but It's too hard when too many contacts in AddressBook.

How to query AddressBook contacts according to the given number？

Comment: possible duplicate of [what the best method to query addressbook contact with a phone number?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9406181/what-the-best-method-to-query-addressbook-contact-with-a-phone-number)

Answer (score 0):

Try to loop the contacts in other thread in background. Try [Grand Central Dispatch](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html).